# div height not increasing to surround child content

Tags: html, css

I created an input field in a `div`

The `div` height is auto but unfortunately the `searchbar_home` `div` height is not increasing to surround my input box and submit button.

Here's my HTML

```
  <div id='container'>    
    <div id="content">
        <h1 class="home_title">English to Malayalam</h1>
        <div id="searchbar_home">
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>Copy right only for me ;)</p>
    </footer>

  </div>​
```

My CSS:

```
#searchbar_home{
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: 80%;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;

    border-radius: 6px;
}
#searchbar_home:after{
    clear: both;
}
#searchbar_home input[type="text"]{
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: none;

    border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
}
#searchbar_home input[type="submit"]{
    float: left;
    background: #414141;
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
}​
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/De7um/) on jsfiddle.

[image: here the image demo]

How do I get the `searchbar_home``div' to increase in size?

Comment: in css height defaults to auto if no other height property is specified, so you don't need height auto, you need something else.

Comment: The container collapses because its children float (which they don't need). See what happens if you just remove the `float: left` in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/De7um/31/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah you've tried to use the :after trick for clearing your floats?

From your code:

```
    #searchbar_home:after{
         clear: both;
    }
```

You'll need to actually give it some content and make it a block item rather than inline -

```
    #searchbar_home:after{
         content:'';
         display:block;
         clear: both;
    }
```

Should work.

Answer (score 16):

I assume you've floated your `input`. To make the `div` size to fit it, add an `overflow:auto;` rule to it's style.

Comment: also to save you some wasted lines, delete the height: auto; it does nothing.